# Using fullpage.js - Is it possible to have the elements on each slide load in sequentially?

Tags: jquery, fadein, viewport, sequential, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js to create a http://www.apple.com/uk/iphone-5s/ like effect.

It's working fine however I need to fade a bunch of separate elements sequentially on the slides but only once the respective elements slide had been selected/activated.

I believe the best way to do this is setting the elements to onLoad on a select viewport, except whenever I attempt to do this I seem to be running into jQuery conflict issues with fullpage-js or vice versa.

Can anyone recommend a solution?

Thanks

Comment: You can see http://onlinedepartment.nl/#cases for an example of what I'm trying to recreate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you are trying it so execute some code for each slide once the user reaches it, then you can do it using the [`afterLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterload-anchorlink-index) or the [`onLeave`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction) events.

Here you have a living example of this use:
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/callbacks.html

Your initialization should look similar to:

```
$.fn.fullpage({
    'afterLoad': function (anchorLink, index) {
        //for section 2...
        if (index == 2) {
            //whatever
        }
    },

    'onLeave': function (index, nextIndex, direction) {
        //going from section 3 to 4
        if (index == 3 && direction == 'down') {
           //whatever
        }

        //going form section 3 to 2
        else if (index == 3 && direction == 'up') {
           //whatever
        }
    }
});
```

If what you want is to do something on the slides rather than on the sections, then you should use the even [`afterSlideLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex).

Comment: I thought I already responded to this, my apologies, your advice worked perfectly. Great plugin Alvaro.